# In Lord Byron's "Don Juan," what was the lead character "half-smother'd" by?

Tags: meaning, poetry, lord-byron, don-juan, wordplay

This would be the character's first adventure. Julia, a married woman, became his mistress. Her husband, Don Alfonso, was told that she was cheating on him and ran into the bedroom, accompanied by servants, in order to surprise her and her lover.

Anticipating this, Julia asked her maid to lie in bed with her, while Don Juan squeezed in between them and was hidden completely by the sheets.

Don Alfonso and the servants searched the entire room, looked under the bed, and failed to find Julia's lover. Julia, pretending to be insulted, shouted at her husband who, realizing he had been misled, hung his head in shame and left.

No sooner did the maid bolt the bedroom's door than Don Juan sprang from the bed "half-smother'd."

Now, pay attention:

> He had been hid—I don’t pretend to say
> How, nor can I indeed describe the where—
> Young, slender, and pack’d easily, he lay,
> No doubt, in little compass, round or square;
> But pity him I neither must nor may
> His **suffocation** by that pretty pair;
> ’Twere better, sure, to die so, than be shut
> With maudlin Clarence in his Malmsey butt.
>
> ```
> [...]
> ```
>
> Of his position I can give no notion:
> ’Tis written in the Hebrew Chronicle,
> How the physicians, leaving pill and potion,
> Prescribed, by way of blister, a young belle,
> When old King David’s blood grew dull in motion,
> And that the medicine answer’d very well;
> Perhaps ’twas in a different way applied,
> For David lived, but Juan **nearly died**.

Now: what exactly did he nearly die *of*?

Were they squashing him?

Or was it the smell?

Or just the lack of air?

What is Byron getting at here?

Comment: I agree that this question is better on Literature SE, but Juan nearly died of being stabbed, or some other violence, which Don Alfonso would have inflicted on him if he had been discovered.

Comment: Wasn't he hiding between two women tightly inside the bedclothes and under their breasts? Smothered is an exaggeration.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a joke, a *double entendre*.

> **die, *v.* I.6.e.** 1600– *intransitive.* To experience sexual orgasm. Now somewhat *archaic.*
>
> <sub>*Oxford English Dictionary*.</sub>

In the plain reading of the stanzas, Juan “nearly died” because he was unable to breathe, but in the lewd reading, Juan nearly came because he was sexually excited by being squeezed between the two women.

Even in the plain reading, we have a choice about how to take “suffocation” and “nearly died”. Perhaps this is hyperbole, or perhaps his mouth and nose were indeed covered by pillows, bedding, or the bodies of Julia and Antonia, so that he was in danger of literal suffocation. Byron leaves this up to our imagination: “I don’t pretend to say how, nor can I indeed describe the where”.

Comment: So this question actually had an answer appropriate for English.SE, even though it was migrated here.

Comment: @PeterShor: Curious, isn't it?

Comment: @Ricky I'm happy it was migrated as it was a fun question that I would otherwise have missed!

Comment: @GarethRees: Much obliged. It remains a fun question. I up-voted your answer, but I can't agree with it completely: Byron does use the word "suffocation" earlier in the text.

Comment: @Ricky Ah, I didn't realise that would still be a difficulty. I've updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: What's your take on "be shut
With maudlin Clarence in his Malmsey butt"? :)

Comment: @Lambie Do I need a take? It's a reference to a rumour about the manner of death of George Plantagenet, Duke of Clarence, as portrayed in Shakespeare's *Richard III* I.4.

Comment: Thank you. I did not know that. But what is Malmsey butt? In the searchable Shakepeare I see malmsey-butt in lower case and with a hyphen and I still have zero idea of what is means. "I'll drown you in the malmsey-butt within." and "Take him over the costard with the hilts of thy sword, and then we will chop him in the malmsey-butt in the next room." The historical plays are the ones with which I am the least familiar. I didn't mean take sarcastically at all.

Comment: @Lambie *Malmsey* was a strong sweet wine (like modern-day Madeira); a *butt* is a barrel. Supposedly Clarence was murdered by being drowned in a barrel of wine.

Comment: Yeah, the wine yes, butt as barrel I didn't know. Thanks.

Comment: @GarethRees: Byron's idea, then, is "Interpret it any way you like, ha, ha, ha." Okay, that's plausible. Thank you!